# netbeans to ruby project vm in vmware player

Tags: ruby, netbeans, vmware

Wondering how to connect from netbeans ide to ruby project vm in vmware player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

netbeans does not support ruby anymore, did you considered switching to [Ruby Mine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) ?

Comment: thanks sir!!! I will try that out. i hope it can connect to a virtual ruby server in vmware player